# Decimal Model Binder not working

Tags: c#, decimal, globalization, modelbinders, custom-model-binder

I have a custom DecimalModelBinder which read decimals by using the current culture. Here is the BindModel implementation

```
public override object BindModel( ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext ) {
    var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue( bindingContext.ModelName );
    var modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
    object actualValue = null;
    try {
        if ( valueResult != null ) {
            actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal( valueResult.AttemptedValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture );
        }
        else {
            actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal( 0 );
        }
    }
    catch ( FormatException e ) {
        modelState.Errors.Add( e );
    }
    bindingContext.ModelState.Add( bindingContext.ModelName, modelState );
    return actualValue;
}
```

This implementation works quite well when the number is written correctly. 
Suppose we have to represent the number `thirty-seven` and `twenty-two`.

If the `CurrentCulture` is `en-US` the user input is `37.22`
If the `currentCulture` is `it-IT` the user input is `37,22`
(note that the decimal separator is different)
In this case the model binder works quite good.

However if the `CurrentCulture` is, for example, `it-IT` and the user input is `37.22` (like the US culture) the number get transformed in `3722,00` because the dot is the thousand separator in `it-IT`.

Is there any way to correct the code of the model binder to protect against these types of errors?